# How to remove a repository in Fossil?

Tags: fossil

Yepp, I'm quite new to Fossil…

During my experiments I've faced a problem: `fossil all info` command lists all and every repos ever touched here including those removed/deleted/dropped/erased/got-rid-of quite obviously failing like that

```
************* /home/jno/src/dropped-repo.fossil *****************************************
SQLITE_CANTOPEN: cannot open file at line 36667 of [0c55d17973]
SQLITE_CANTOPEN: os_unix.c:36667: (21) open(/home/jno/src/dropped-repo.fossil) - 
fossil: [/home/jno/src/dropped-repo.fossil]: unable to open database file
```

Yes, the `--dontstop` flag makes the life a bit easier, but does not fix the things.

So, the question is: **how to *properly* remove a repository?**

The only way I found so far is:

- `fossil close` it
- remove the repo file itself
- run `sqlite3 ~/.fossil` and `delete from global_config where name='…'` on all mentions of that repo.

This looks ugly.

I see a `new`/`init` command to **create** a repo, but I see no way to remove it.

PS. The recipie from [Fossil: "not a valid repository" - deleted repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243374/fossil-not-a-valid-repository-deleted-repository?rq=1) (just `rm ~/.fossil`) looks an overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `fossil all` command to ignore a certain (past or present) repository, you should use [`fossil all ignore`](https://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help?cmd=all).

In short:

- `fossil close` closes a working directory (by deleting the `.fslckout` file)
- `rm /home/jno/src/dropped-repo.fossil` actually deletes the repository (only do this if you really want to throw away the entire repository, including all versions)
- `fossil all ignore /home/jno/src/dropped-repo.fossil` removes the repository from the list of repositories that's used by the `fossil all` command.

Comment: Yes, it is!


   **ignore**      Arguments are repositories that should be ignored by subsequent clean, extras, list, pull, push, rebuild, and sync operations.  The -c|--ckout option causes the listed local checkouts to be ignored instead.